# Drupal6: Theming Node Edit pages / Opening within Lightbox

Tags: drupal, themes, lightbox, user-experience

I'm trying to display all node_edit form neatly within a lightbox without any of the excess content I don't want. No sidebars, footer, header, nothing. Just the content. So I created a page-node-edit.tpl.php file.

I have two problems daunting me, but for now I'll only mention the first since its more important.

1) From any drupal page, clicking on the "edit" link for the node doesn't activate the lightbox like it should. Instead it clicks-thru the link as normal.

With jQuery in the header I added a rel attribute for the lightbox to the links, but the box still doesn't activate. I tested the lightbox on a link I hardcoded into the page, and it activated just fine. For elements generated by Drupal, like the node edit link/button the problem seems to be timing.

I think the rel attribute needs to be built with the page, with the link, rather than appended onto it. The catch is, the link lacks an id and class, so I don't see how the hook_alter_link() function can help me.

I'm willing to try anything. Perhaps someone has done this before? Opened a node/edit form within a lightbox.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be a good question for the Drupal SE site: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't have a solution unfortunately, but I thought I'd comment here that it is amazing to me that there is no contrib module to do this.  It seems like such an obvious need, and one that I could sure use...The closest I've seen is the Popup API, but it is unreliable for this, IME.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also disappointed something with this functionality doesn't already exist for all to use and share. But I've read others have had some success doing this or something similar in their own private projects. So he's my effort to duplicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the Modal Frame API used in a few modules (Node Relationships uses it to do something very similar to what you're doing); might be helpful...

http://drupal.org/project/modalframe

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Aendrew. I'll try it out and see if it works as needed.

Comment: The ModalFrame module didn't work out quite like how I hoped, but it did give me a few ideas. I will continue to investigate on my end, but any further assistance is still greatly appreciated. (Also, I have made a post on the Drupal SE as well)

Comment: After such a long time, I've returned to this project and I've managed to get an alternative solution working with CTools modals! The link you provided Aendrew turned out to be a very helpful. Thanks!